# I can ping to an IP address and its name but I can't get access using browser

Tags: linux, networking, dns

So as the title said, after setting the IP and the host name on `/etc/hosts`, I can ping both of them. I confirm it can resolve by `resolvectl query`. 
The thing is: When I try to access a service of this host: let's say HDFS: `<hostname>:9870` it can't be accessed but `<ip-addr>:9870` can.[image]

I tried flushing the DNS but it is still not working.

More details:

- We have our own DNS server.
- I set two IP addresses and their host names on `/etc/hosts`, and surprisingly, one worked and the other didn't.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: That looks like an error from the Squid proxy server. You should exclude this hostname from proxying in your browser settings.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to be a linux-specific problem and should likely be posted on SuperUser instead.